# How to create asp.net dataset freetext query

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, full-text-search, freetext

I have a database with a fulltext catalog setup for one of my tables and the goal is to be able to conduct a freetext search against that table from an asp.net c# website. Using SQL Management Studio, I can manually run the queries such as:

```
SELECT ProductName
FROM   Products
WHERE FREETEXT(ProductName, 'ABC')
```

But when I add a SQL query in an dataset and pass a parameter to it as follow

```
SELECT ProductName
FROM   Products
WHERE FREETEXT(ProductName, @ProductName)
```

the wizard returns an error

```
The @ProductName SQL construct or statement is not supported
```

How can I create a strongly-type dataset query that support full-text search ?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @Keith I use wizard to add queries to a dataset in Visual Studio, there is no code, as it is auto generated. Normaly, I can create queries with [WHERE ABC = @ABC], but when I change the condition to [WHERE FREETEXT(ProductName, @ProductName)] - the wizard returns an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to create a store procedure with parameter and call it from the Add query wizard. It still alerts a  message but runs just well.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_FreetextProductName] 
    @ProductName nvarchar(500)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ProductName
    FROM   Products
    WHERE FREETEXT(ProductName, @ProductName)
END
```